# Why do I get IllegalMonitorException in a synchronized block?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String resource1 = "ratan jaiswal";
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (resource1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (resource1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
```

After I run this code I get 
line 16 is the line with the wait() call

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at ThreadSyncFromMark.deadlock.dead$1.run(dead.java:16)
```

Why I get this exception as I see everything is OK here because t1 owns the monitor of resource1 when it call wait

Comment: From the doc : _Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why I get this exception as I see everything is OK here because t1 owns the monitor of resource1 when it call wait

Yes, `t1` owns the monitor of `resource1`. But you're not calling `resource1.wait()`, you're calling `this.wait()`.

You need to `synchronize`, `wait()` and `notify()` all on the same object (monitor) to make things work the way they should.